# Windows worker service WebApplication api memory problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a windows worker service and it collects lots of realtime data in memory.
I create a WebApplication in this service and serve thousands data from api request.
But with every request, memory usage increases. Memory just increases with every request. Think that 100 requests per seconds. How can i prevent memory usage with every request? Here is my api code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("get/")]
 [MatriksAuthorize]
 public async IAsyncEnumerable<TradePackage> GetTick([FromForm] int symbolId, [FromForm] int exchangeId, [FromForm] string subMarketCode)
 {
 
 var termId = RouteData.Values["TermId"]?.ToString();
 var categoryId = RouteData.Values["CategoryId"]?.ToString();
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(termId)) yield return null; ;

 var licenses = _userLicenseManager.GetUserLicense(termId, categoryId);
 var result = _tickDataCollector.GetTickData(symbolId, licenses, exchangeId, subMarketCode);
 if (result != null)
     foreach (TradePackage tradePackageBase in result)
     {
         yield return tradePackageBase;
     }
 
 }
```

Here is my data structure:

```
public class TradePackage
{  
[JsonPropertyName("d")]
public virtual bool IsDelayed { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("r")]
public bool IsRefresh { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("bt")]
public bool IsBlockTrade { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("i")]
public int SymbolId { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("tno")]
public uint TransactionNo { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("p")]
public double Price { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("sz")]
public double Size { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("ba")]
public BidAsk BidAsk { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("no")]
public bool NoHasTransactionDirection { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("b")]
public int BuyerId { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("s")]
public int SellerId { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("t")]
public TimeSpan TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough context to know if there are any memory management issues. But, why asyncenumerable if you don't have any async calls?

Comment: How did you measure memory usage? Are you running the program using the debugger? The debugger will track all objects *and* their metadata, resulting in far greater memory usage

Comment: Have you tried a memory profiler? It's impossible to tell where the problem is from the bit of code you are showing. It could be `_userLicenseManager` or `_tickDataCollector` that cause memory pressure.

Comment: The code you posted isn't *worker* code either. It's an ASP.NET Core project that loads stuff using `GetUserLicense` and `GetTickData`. If those methods are inefficient, each request will use a lot of memory. We can't guess what they do though, so we can't say what's eating up RAM

Comment: If `GetTickData` inserts items into a List one by one for example, the List will have to reallocate its internal buffer every time it runs out. This can result in `log2(N)` reallocations, 2*N RAM usage and N orphaned objects. If the missing code performs a lot of string modifications, it will create a new temporary string for each modification. All these temporary objects will remain in memory until the garbage collector runs